# Angular submit a form from TypeScript

Tags: angular

I want submit a form from TypeScript. I have a few form validation directives that listen to the submit event on the form so I need to submit the form and not just emit from the ngForm's event emitter.

The only thing I have come up with so far is to click on the submit button but it feels dirty.

```
(document.querySelector('button[type="submit"]') as HTMLElement).click();
```

Does anybody have any other suggestions for getting the native form element to submit?

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question I changed the way my focus first invalid directive works. The directive listens to the submit event on the form and looks for any ng-invalid classes and then focuses the first one if there are any.

I changed the directive from listening to the submit event

```
@HostListener('submit', ['$event'])
onSubmit(event) {
```

to injecting the ngForm object and subscribing to the submit event emitter.

```
constructor(form: NgForm, el: ElementRef) {
    this.subscription = form.ngSubmit.subscribe(_ => {
        this.onSubmit(el.nativeElement);
    });
}
```

Now the directive fires when the Angular ngForm object submits and I don't need to worry about the native DOM event.

Answer (score -2):

it is not recommend to use query in angular app. you can use `ViewChild` to get the form element.

Comment: I have tried that but calling submit on the native element causes the form to do a full post back to the server and the whole app reloads

Comment: if you want to submit the form in a async way, you can use `FormData` api (https://caniuse.com/#search=FormData)

Comment: and if you want to validate the form by hand, please refer to the `NgForm` api here https://angular.io/api/forms/NgForm